# How to resolve "isn't in GROUP BY" error in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two models: `posts` and `likings` which have one-to-many relationship (so, one post has many likes). Likings model has also an `isActive` field which shows liking is active or passive.

I want to get (sort) top 5 posts which had received maximum "active" likes (only likes whose isActive field is true would be considered).

This is the query:

```
select posts.*, count(likings.id) as likes_count from 'posts'
left join 'likings' on 'likings'.'post_id' = 'posts'.'id' and 'likings'.'isActive' = 1
group by 'posts'.'id'
order by 'likes_count' desc 
limit 5
```

which is resulted from this laravel query:

```
Post::selectRaw('posts.*, count(likes.id) as likes_count')
    ->leftJoin('likes', function ($join) {
        $join->on('likes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
             ->where('likes.is_active', '=', 1);
    })
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

And this is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
'database.posts.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Here, `posts.user_id` is also a field of `posts` table and shows the owner of the post.

How can I resolve this error? It seems it isn't logical to change mysql config (probably deleting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode), but minimum change in the query.

Comment: By standard, you must to list every selected field in the `group clause` or to use one of aggregate functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each non-aggregated field should be grouped.

It is standard behavior, which in mysql, depends on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.
This mode is default enabled in >= `5.7`.

```
select posts.id, post.user_id, count(likings.id) as likes_count
from posts
left join likings on likings.post_id = posts.id and likings.isActive= 1
group by posts.id, posts.user_id
order by likes_count desc 
limit 5
```

Or, you can `aggregate` it:

```
select posts.id, MIN(post.user_id), count(likings.id) as likes_count
from posts
left join likings on likings.post_id = posts.id and likings.isActive= 1
group by posts.id
order by likes_count desc 
limit 5
```

Other way - change `sql_mode`:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
```

Also, you can divide it to 2 query:

1. Get aggregate and post ids
2. Get posts data with fetched ids (with `IN clause`)

Comment: I need all fields of the posts. Can't I start the query with posts.*

Comment: You can, but you can't to do it in the group clause. Other option is to change  `sql_mode` in `mysql` config or in the session

Comment: Maybe I should write one query more.

Comment: Best answer for this error, all other answers (in other topics) recommending disable config database.strict. and you can do it by using ->groupBy('posts.id','posts.user_id').

Comment: What the hell is that? I dont understand the reason why this should be the default behavior? WHY?

Answer (score 4):

In 5.7 the sqlmode is set by default to:

> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

To remove the clause ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY you can do this:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: can it cause any problems if we did this ?

Comment: Why this is default? what is the reason?

Comment: Because not full group by actually does not make sense. if you sure, you have unique values in a grouped subsets, just add it into group by, if not, how can dbms be correct then?