# GroupBy in Laravel 5.3 and PHP 7 not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

Group by is problematic since I switched to PHP 7 and having aggregate values doesn't apply to the way I want to use it.

I've got a list and sometimes there are repeats in the list. For example:

Song Title A Song Title B Song Title A (reprise) Song Title C

In the results, Song Title A should only show up once. Previously, I had done this with group by, where the ID that determines the song title is grouped.

My table structure is:

```
id
group_id
song_title_id
```

Song_title_id relates to:

```
id
song_title
```

In the first table, there can be multiple instances of the same song_title_id. And when results are returned, I want there to only one instance of each song_title_id in the results.

Previously, I'd have done:

```
DB::table('group_songs')
         ->groupBy('song_title_id')
         ->get();
```

Since updating to PHP 7, I get an error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 '[table/column name]' isn't in GROUP BY
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
'mysql' => [
    'strict' => false,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

By [How to resolve "isn't in GROUP BY" error in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591606/how-to-resolve-isnt-in-group-by-error-in-mysql-query) 
Each non-aggregated field should be grouped, so try

```
DB::table('group_songs')
         ->groupBy('song_title_id')
         ->groupBy('group_id')
         ->groupBy('id')
          ->get();
```

Comment: So, every single column in the table would need to be included in groupBy?

Comment: Do I need to list every single column in the table? Could the same thing be done with distinct?

Comment: You can add just single groupBy and single select 
'DB::table('group_songs')
          ->select('song_title_id')
         ->groupBy('song_title_id')
          ->get();'
but if you need all off columns you will need group them or add group function (like MIN/MAX) on not grouped columns