# Does mariaDB NOT support functional dependencies in SELECT statements when GROUPing?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am having a few issues with GROUP BY in my SQL statements.

I am utilising mariaDB 10.1.17 and have noticed that I am getting errors when executing SQL statements such as the following:

```
SELECT `pubs`.`ID` AS `ID`
    ,AVG(`reviews`.`atmosphere`) AS `average`
    ,`pubs`.`name` AS `name`
    ,`pubs`.`country` AS `country`
FROM `pubs`
LEFT JOIN `reviews` ON `pubs`.`ID` = `reviews`.`pub_ID`
GROUP BY `pubs`.`ID`
ORDER BY `average` DESC
    ,`reviews`.`date` DESC
```

The error that i get is

> "Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'pubreviews.pubs.name' isn't
>   in GROUP BY"

My understanding was that such columns did not need to be explicitly added to the group by statement because of 'functional dependencies' - the fact that one ID maps to one name and country.

(I have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` 'turned on')

This is what seems to be implied [here](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html) re MySQL 5.7.5

Given this error message.. does mariaDB not implement this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591606/how-to-resolve-isnt-in-group-by-error-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 4):

Based on mariadb documentation, it seems that it does not consider functional dependencies if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql mode is turned on.

The documentation on [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql_mode/) sql mode says:

> For SELECT ... GROUP BY queries, disallow SELECTing columns which are not referred to in the GROUP BY clause, unless they are passed to an aggregate function like COUNT() or MAX(). Produce a 1055 error.

So, there is no hint of functional dependencies.

I also checked what the documentation says about the [group by](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/select/#group-by) clause:

> If you select a non-grouped column or a value computed from a non-grouped column, it is undefined which row the returned value is taken from. This is not permitted if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL_MODE is used.

Again, there is no hint of functional dependencies.

The above are valid as of mariadb version 10.1.18 and 10.2.2.

Comment: Thanks for this. Whilst this seems to be clear.. surely not? Why would the open source version of MySQL NOT implement functional dependencies..? and why is it so difficult to find any information about this.. Surely someone else must have been vexed by this..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot guess why a certain functionality is being or not being implemented by an open source project. This is beyond SO.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't, which is surprising given this (IMHO consequential) feature has been in MySQL since late 2014. I've opened a ticket addressing this: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11588

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB was forked from MySQL 5.5, then they developed some original features, and added some selected features backported from subsequent MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 versions.

There are features of MySQL developed after version 5.5 that are impractical to backport, because the implementation depends on refactored code. The divergence in feature set will become greater as time goes on.

If you need the features of MySQL 5.7, you should use MySQL 5.7. Or else you could backport that MySQL 5.7 feature to MariaDB yourself, and contribute your code.

Re your comment:
*Why would the open source version of MySQL NOT implement functional dependencies..?*

Calling MariaDB the "open source version of MySQL" implies that MySQL is not open source. That's a misunderstanding. MySQL Community Edition continues to be open source, offered under the GNU Public License.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which name you get, change

```
`pubs`.`name`
```

to

```
ANY_VALUE(`pubs`.`name`)
```

The improved sophistication of 5.7.5 may not have been merged into MariaDB yet.

Comment: `ANY_VALUE()` is actually also not supported in MariaDB as of yet. There's a ticket from July '16, but no activity as of yet: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10426

Comment: `MAX(pubs.name)` or some other artificial way of "picking one" will work instead.

Comment: It will. But... argh. Would rather have it understand functional dependency. Otherwise, I'd rather just turn the over-restrictive SQL mode off. Just opened a ticket at Maria about this. Been two years in MySQL.

Comment: It's a SQL standard -- MySQL has, until recently, be lax on it.

Comment: SQL '92 requires all non-aggregated selected columns to be referenced in the GROUP BY clause. SQL '03 relaxes this by requiring only functional dependence that ensures deterministic results. MySQL 5.7.5, unlike apparently most other RDBMSes, now implements this very much to the '03 spec. More info in this ticket, along with the linked reads: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11588

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the desired result, without any group-by complaints.

```
SELECT pubs.`ID`,
       r.`average`,
       pubs.`name`,
       pubs.`country`
    FROM `pubs`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT pub_id,
               AVG(atmosphere) AS 'average'
               MAX(date) AS 'last_review'  -- which `date` do you want?
            FROM reviews
            GROUP BY pub_id
              ) AS r  ON r.pub_id = pubs.ID
    ORDER BY `average` DESC, last_review DESC
```

You might consider whether you really need `LEFT`.  With a regular `JOIN`, the query would probably run a lot faster.