# How to hide repetitive data while retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have this function:

```
public function readData(){
$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
->select(
    'users.name as name',
    'group_user.user_id as id',
    'groups.name as groupname',
    'meetings.owned_by_id as meetings'
)
->groupBy('users.id')
->get();
```

I get this error :

[image]

When I remove the `groupBy` part it works but repetitive data like this 
it returns data like this :

```
[{"name":"Mohamed Adel","id":6,"groupname":"Team Mohamed","meetings":6},{"name":"Mohamed Adel","id":6,"groupname":"Team Mohamed","meetings":6},{"name":"Norman Osborn","id":2,"groupname":"Team Mohamed","meetings":2},{"name":"Harry Osborn","id":3,"groupname":"Team Harry","meetings":3}]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly what the error told you. To oversimplify, if it’s in the select, it must be in the group by.

Comment: sorry im new i don't quite understand.
how to solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "isn't in GROUP BY" error in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591606/how-to-resolve-isnt-in-group-by-error-in-mysql-query)

Comment: In standard SQL, you must either name all selected fields in the group by, or use an aggregate function like sum() or max() etc in the select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
public function readData()
{
    $TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
        ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
        ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
        ->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
        ->select(
            'users.id as user_id',
            'users.name as name',
            'group_user.user_id as id',
            'groups.name as groupname',
            'meetings.owned_by_id as meetings'
        )
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->get();
```

Change config\database.php to

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false, // must be false
    'engine' => null
],
```

Comment: Is this a non standard feature of MySQL, or is it something this framework does for you?  Seems like this is encouraging learning something the wrong way... (I sure wish I could do this in DB2)